# How can you use the unix kill command silently in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to check if a particular process is running, and if it is, try and kill it.

I've come up with the following so far:

```
PID=$(ps aux | grep myprocessname | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')

if [ -z $PID];
then    
    echo Still running on PID $PID, attempting to kill..
    kill -9 $PID > /dev/null
fi
```

However when I run this, I get the following output:

```
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

What is the best way to kill a running process on unix silently?

Comment: Are you sure you wanted `-z`? `-n` seems more likely, `if [[ -n $PID ]]`.

Comment: does this work?: kill -s 9 $PID > /dev/null

Comment: Tangentially, ITYM `ps aux | awk '/[m]yprocessname/{print $2}'`. See also http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[ -z $PID]
```

is true if `$PID` is empty, not the other way around, so your test is inverted.

You should be using `pgrep` if you have that on your system too. (Or even better: [`pkill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) and stop worrying about all that shell logic.)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is easier
The program "killall" is part of almost any distribution.

Examples:

```
killall name_of_process &> /dev/null
killall -9 name_of_process &> /dev/null
(( $? == 0)) && echo "kill successful";
```

Now there also is "pkill" and "pgrep"
Example:

```
pkill -9 bash &> /dev/null
(( $? == 0)) && echo "kill successful";
```

Example:

```
for pid in $(pgrep bash); do
 kill -9 $pid &> /dev/null
 (( $? == 0)) && echo "kill of $pid successful" || echo "kill of $pid failed";
done
```

And last as you used "ps" in your example, here a better way to use it without the requirement of "grep" "grep -v" and "awk":

```
PIDS="$(ps -a -C myprocessname -o pid= )"
while read pid; do 
  kill -9 $pid &> /dev/null
  ((!$?)) && echo -n "killed $pid,"; 
done <<< "$p"
```

All those listed methods are better than the long pipe-pipe-pipe imho

Comment: pkill is however not equal to killall; the former does a substring regex grep, which can be... potentially dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

Try `if [ X$PID != X ]` in your condition. This is the usual idiom for checking whether a string is empty.