# How to stop a c++ code from running

Tags: linux

I clicked on a.out of a code in Linux, now I want to stop running code but as I didn't use the terminal, I don't know that how can I stop the code from running. What can I do?
I am running another code from last week.
I can not kill both by turn off the computer because the first code is running from previous week and I don't have time to run it again

Comment: ctrl+c combination?

Comment: Time to learn about the `kill` command.

Comment: Turn off the machine

Comment: I'm running another code in terminal and I afraid if I press ctr+c that code stop running @AndreySemenov

Comment: I am not sure but `ps -ef | grep <process_name>` may help.  Kill the resulting process id.

Comment: I can not. Because I am running another code @DavyM

Comment: I don't know the process name @Sid

Comment: @MatheMa Kill both, don't care. Rinse, flush, start over. Process name is `a.out` BTW.

Comment: This may help @MatheMa : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11934701/259889

Comment: I can not kill both because the first code is running from previous week and I don't have time to run it again @user0042

Comment: @MatheMa Good experience to learn, naming your programs different than `a.out`. Well, you can check the PID. A common heuristics says that the PID of the incidentially started process should be bigger than your precious long runner.

Comment: Please provide an exact answer, I do really need your help because my computer will damp if both run together

Comment: What should I do after that? please help me I really afraid that computer dump :( @user0042

Comment: pidof a.out 
output is: 19564 7735
@user0042

Comment: @MatheMa So the question is which is the bigger number?

Comment: Is it correct to use 'pidof a.out ' to find pid of the process I ran by mistake? @user0042

Comment: Open a terminal and run `pgrep a.out`, what does it say?

Comment: @yacc 7735
19564

Comment: Run `ps -ef | grep a.out` what does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you're running two instances of a.out (which I'm just assuming because your question is unclear...) then, as other users have said, run:

```
pgrep a.out
```

If the second a.out process is the one you want to kill, take the larger PID number (in your case it seems to be 19564) and run:

```
kill 19564
```